# startActivity(intent) works if using singleInstance, but doesn't start a new instance with Launchmode=standard

Tags: android, android-intent

In Android Studio, I have three activities A, B and C. In activity A there is an intent which starts B. then there are intents in B and C which intends to start each other with new instances, i.e. B starts C, or C starts B.

When using `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, B and C can start each other with the existing instances. However if using `android:launchMode="standard"` (or default), the application stops when the button for `startActivity(intent)` is pressed. 
Is there any clue to solve this problem? thanks!

Comment: Can you add the log for the related issue when the app stops?

Comment: @ BMacedo Thanks for the reminder. I studied Logcat and found the problems in other parts of the code-though there is a bit I can't explain.

Comment: @ BMacedo 1: Intent for A -> B is okay, with two putExtra("xx",yy) passing variables, while with C -> B the variables were not provided.Using "singleinstance" displayed the existing instance of B triggered by A. 2: after that, A->B, B->C, C->B became ok, then subsequent B->C stops app. The issue is an arraylist in C, that ArrayList[0] was called before it was initialized. In the updated code the initialization of arraylist is re-ordered and passed the compilation. However I couldn't explain why the first B->C was ok.